# Creating a global array of objects in a View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am creating a simple ToDo application to learn the Objective-C language. The initial view is a Tableview Controller and the cells display the diffrent Todo's.

Here is my code in the Swift Language:

```
var toDos:[ToDo]=[
    ToDo(taskTitle: "Feed the dog", taskDeadline: "11/23/2016", finishedState: .finished),
    ToDo(taskTitle: "Eat Food", taskDeadline: "12/23/2016", finishedState: .notFinished),
    ToDo(taskTitle: "Clean Up Room", taskDeadline: "10/13/2016", finishedState: .finished)
]

// MARK: ViewDidLoad

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Here is my code for ObJective-C

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _arrayOfTodos = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [_arrayOfTodos addObject: [[Todo alloc]initWithInformation:@"Fly Back to SF" todoDeadline:@"8/6/17" todoStatus:inProgress]];
    [_arrayOfTodos addObject: [[Todo alloc]initWithInformation:@"Wash Clothes" todoDeadline:@"4/11/17" todoStatus:inProgress]];
    [_arrayOfTodos addObject: [[Todo alloc]initWithInformation:@"Read Books" todoDeadline:@"5/11/17" todoStatus:unfinished]];
    [_arrayOfTodos addObject: [[Todo alloc]initWithInformation:@"Cook Pasta" todoDeadline:@"3/9/17" todoStatus:finished]];
    [_arrayOfTodos addObject: [[Todo alloc]initWithInformation:@"Feed Dog" todoDeadline:@"1/1/17" todoStatus:finished]];
}
```

Notice how in the swift version, the array is created above the `viewDidLoad`.
This allows me to use that array throughout that View Controller.

Notice in the Objective-C version, the array is created and populated in the `viewDidLoad`. This poses as a problem because when I  add a new `Todo` object, and then call the `[self.tableView reloadData];` to update the view, it calls the `viewDidLoad` method and it re-inits the array. As a result, its like I never added the new `ToDo` object in the first place (Because the array is re-initialized and re-populated by the Todo object initializers (See how I add to the array below).

The line below adds to the the `_arrayOfTodos`.

`[_arrayOfTodos addObject: [[Todo alloc]initWithInformation:@"Fly Back to SF" todoDeadline:@"8/6/17" todoStatus:inProgress]];`

I would like to know how to create an array of `ToDo` objects ABOVE the view did load (or someplace else I can use it globally in the Controller).

Here is my MainVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Todo.h"

@class Todo;

@interface MainVC : UITableViewController
-(void)addNewTodo:(Todo *)todo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayOfTodos;
@end
```

Comment: `[self.tableView reloadData]` doesn't call `viewDidLoad`. `viewDidLoad` is called only once, so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: why does it go through its methods and creates another array then? @Vishnugondlekar

Comment: It would be better to use Singleton. See here: https://xcodenoobies.blogspot.my/2012/08/how-to-pass-data-between.html

Comment: @MarquaviousDraggon Check out Objective-C's literal syntax. It'll save you a lot of `addObject:` visual clutter: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: @MarquaviousDraggon set a breakpoint at the point the array gets created and you'll find out why that happens

Answer (score 0):

You can take this array in `AppDelegate.h`

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>  {
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayOfTodos;
```

And you can access it any where in project using this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.arrayOfTodos addObject: [[Todo alloc]initWithInformation:@"Fly Back to SF" todoDeadline:@"8/6/17" todoStatus:inProgress]];
```

Would be better if you create a `Global` class for all such global data and function.

Comment: I don't think I should create variables in the app delegate. How do I replicate the swift version? In the swift version, I could just make an array of objects and use it in the View Controller. is there not an Objective - C equivalent?

Comment: See first You have to decide whether you want to access it with using MainVC object or Some Global class object?

Comment: if you want to access it using MainVC object so u need to take it in Appdelagate. As you have already created a property of  @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayOfTodos; so you can access in every where in project but using MainVC object only MainVC *obj; obj.arrayOfTodos like this. First you clear what you want i will provide you solution with code

Comment: What is the issue @iOS Developer

Comment: her is the link of my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49773206/adding-objects-in-array-of-app-delegate-from-view-controller-objective-c-ios

Answer (score 0):

As you have explained in your above question by

> The line below adds to the the _arrayOfTodos.
>
> [_arrayOfTodos addObject: [[Todo alloc]initWithInformation:@"Fly Back
>   to SF" todoDeadline:@"8/6/17" todoStatus:inProgress]];

You will defiantly get the initial array. Because you initialize your array by initializing the `TODO`. Rather you can make a comen object of your `TODO` once when you initializing your array object and using that you can add your object to your array, some what like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _arrayOfTodos = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    _todo = [[Todo alloc] init];
    [_arrayOfTodos addObject: [_todo initWithInformation:@"Fly Back to SF" todoDeadline:@"8/6/17" todoStatus:inProgress]];
    [_arrayOfTodos addObject: [_todo initWithInformation:@"Wash Clothes" todoDeadline:@"4/11/17" todoStatus:inProgress]];
    [_arrayOfTodos addObject: [_todo initWithInformation:@"Read Books" todoDeadline:@"5/11/17" todoStatus:unfinished]];
    [_arrayOfTodos addObject: [_todo initWithInformation:@"Cook Pasta" todoDeadline:@"3/9/17" todoStatus:finished]];
    [_arrayOfTodos addObject: [_todo initWithInformation:@"Feed Dog" todoDeadline:@"1/1/17" todoStatus:finished]];
}
```

Above _todo is a globally declared object which you can declare with array object.
When you use this globally declared object of `TODO`, your array will not re-initialize every time you add a new object.
Hope this may help you and may solve your issue.