# Adding objects in array of app delegate from view controller in Objective-C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Help me in adding objects in array of app delegate from UIViewController in Objective-C I guess I am doing mistake, help me in this regard

I want to add objects in array of app delegate from view controller

in appdelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *sharedArray;
```

in appdelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize sharedArray;
```

inside `didfinishlaunching`

```
self.sharedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

in ViewController

```
@interface ViewController () {

    UIApplication *appDelegate;
```

Inside `viewdidload` of `viewcontroller`

```
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appdelegate.sharedArray addObject:array];
```

Comment: can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: What is your problem here? Anyway, you don't need to declare `appDelegate` in `ViewController`

Comment: I want to add objects in array of app delegate from view controller

Comment: @iOSDeveloper check Anbu's answer.

Comment: replace  UIApplication *appDelegate; with this AppDelegate *appDelegate;

Comment: What is not working? Where you are not able to utilize this code?

Comment: @RealmOfFire it gives error `Unknown type name 'AppDelegate' ` when defining  AppDelegate *appDelegate;

Comment: import AppDelegate where you want to use that

Comment: thanks I forgot to import app delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change declaration of

```
UIApplication *appDelegate;
```

to

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate;
```

//

```
self.appDelegate =  (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

// on top you should

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Comment: Unknown type name 'AppDelegate' it gives this error when doing this

Comment: Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine and correct, but you need to initialize the memory of your array before append the object

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self. sharedArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    return YES;
}
```

finally call the method as

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [appDelegate.sharedArray addObject:array];
```

finally import the header

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Comment: I have added self.sharedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: @RealmOfFire- sure bro, it works, we need the conformation from questioner

Comment: @Anbu.karthik upvoted your answer, but I forgot to import the app delegate